# Javascript Promises: Chain same promise n times, then do something else

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise-returning function that does some async stuff, let's call it `functionToRepeat()`.

I am trying to write the function `repeatFunction(amount)` , so that it will start the promise, wait for completion, start it again, wait for completion, and so on a given amount of times. This `repeatFunction(amount)` should also be thenable, so that I can chain other stuff after it's been executed.

Here is my attempt:

```
function functionToRepeat(){
  let action = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("resolved!");
      resolve()}
    ,1000);
  })
  return action
}

function repeatFunction(amount) {
  if(amount==0){
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  return functionToRepeat().then(function(){
    repeatFunction(amount-1);
  });
}

repeatFunction(5).then(function(){
 console.log("DONE!");
})
```

This successfully chains my promises (or so it seams, I get one "resolved!" per second in the console).
However the `.then()` I try to chain after my `repeatFunction(5)` happens after the 1st promise ends, not after all 5 have ended!

So in my console I get:

resolved!
DONE!
resolved!
resolved!
resolved!
resolved!

What am I doing wrong and what should I change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are almost there, but you have to return the repeatFunction again in the then block of your function to repeat.

```
return functionToRepeat().then(function(){
    return repeatFunction(amount-1);
  });
}
```

If you have a `then`, but do not return anything, then it will just resolve the upper promise. That is what happened.

Answer (score 5):

How about simply:

```
function repeat(func, times) {
  var promise = Promise.resolve();
  while (times-- > 0) promise = promise.then(func);
  return promise;
}
```

When tested with this:

```
function oneSecond() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("tick");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

repeat(oneSecond, 5).then(function () {
    console.log("done");
});
```

this output is produced over 5 seconds:

```
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return` when you call `repeatFunction(amount-1)`

```
function functionToRepeat(){
  let action = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("resolved!");
      resolve()}
    ,1000);
  })
  return action
}

function repeatFunction(amount) {
  if(amount==0){
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  return functionToRepeat().then(function(){
    return repeatFunction(amount-1); // Added return
  });
}

repeatFunction(5).then(function(){
 console.log("DONE!");
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/93T6B4QkBv0mYS4xPw0a?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could use `async`/`await` with a simple `while` loop. This keeps you in Asyncland allows you to continue chaining after the repeated function is done

```
async function asyncRepeat (f, n) {
  while (n-- > 0)
    await f()
}

asyncRepeat(functionToRepeat, 5).then(() => {
  console.log('done')
})

// some value
// some value
// some value
// some value
// some value
// done
```

This is trash tho. You're restricted to using a side-effecting function as your `f` argument to `asyncRepeat`. So logging to the console works, but what if you actually wanted to do something with that value?

Here's an update to `asyncRepeat` that allows you to thread a value thru the repeated application of your input function (`asyncDouble` in this example)

(important changes in **bold**)

```
async function asyncRepeat (f, n, x) {
  while (n-- > 0)
    x = await f(x)
  return x
}

function asyncDouble (x) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('x is currently: %d', x)
      resolve(x * 2) // resolve an actual value
    }, 1000)
  })
}

asyncRepeat(asyncDouble, 5, 2).then(result => {
  console.log('result: %d', result)
})

// x is currently: 2
// x is currently: 4
// x is currently: 8
// x is currently: 16
// x is currently: 32
// result: 64
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar, so I wrote a generic function at (https://repl.it/@turlockmike/BriskLovableLinuxkernel)

```
function repeat(fn, times) {
  if (times == 1) {
    return fn()
  } else {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return fn().then(function() {
        return resolve(repeat(fn,times - 1))
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Usage

```
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     //do something interested here
     setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("resolved!");
       resolve()}
     ,1000);
  })
}

repeat(doSomething, 5).then(() => {
  console.log("all Done!")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const { t, d, r } = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

const checkRoot = config => {
  const { delaySeconds, rootUrl } = config ? config : { delaySeconds: 6 };
  const delay = delaySeconds * 1000;
  const protocolString = rootUrl.split(':')[0];
  const protocol = {
    http: http,
    https: https,
  };
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      protocol[protocolString]
        .get(rootUrl, resp => {
          let data = '';
          resp.on('data', chunk => {
            data += chunk;
          });
          resp.on('end', () => {
            res({ success: data.includes('<!doctype html>') });
          });
        })
        .on('error', err => {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
          res({ success: false });
        });
    }, delay);
  });
};
const repeatChecking = async ({ times, delaySeconds, rootUrl }) => {
  let isReady = false;
  console.log(
    `will try ${times}, and with ${delaySeconds} seconds delay in between for ${rootUrl}`
  );
  let i = 1;
  while (i <= times) {
    if (isReady === true) {
      break;
    }
    const res = await checkRoot({ delaySeconds, rootUrl }).then();
    isReady = res.success;
    console.log(`testing ${i}, status: root ready => ${res.success}`);
    i++;
  }
  if (isReady) {
    console.log('Done, root is ready');
    return;
  }
  process.stdout.write('ERROR: root could not be reached\n');
  process.exit(1);
};

repeatChecking({ times: t, delaySeconds: d, rootUrl: r });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let loopP = (n, f, ...args) => {
  let p = f(...args);
  p.then(res => {
    if (n - 1) {
      loopP(n - 1, f, res);
    }
  });
};
```

Where `n` is the number of iterations, `f` is the Promise-returning function to be called. Each successive call to `f` is passed the results of the previous call when it resolves.

For instance...

```
let addOneP = i => {
  console.log(i + 1);
  return Promise.resolve(i + 1);
};

loopP(5, addOneP, 0);
// logs:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

Comment: This is really nice, but _... This `repeatFunction(amount)` should also be thenable ..._

Answer (score -1):

You might find [relign](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/relign) useful for this kind of thing. Here's your example written with relign [series](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/relign#series) and relign [setTimeout](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/relign#setTimeout).

```
const fnToRepeat = () =>
  relign.setTimeout(() => console.log("resolved!"), 1000);

relign.series((new Array(5)).fill(fnToRepeat))
  .then(() => console.log('done'));
```